# How can I add cards using trello-bot in Slack?

Tags: trello, slack

I just looked up about the commands and couldn't find any commands for what I want.

Answer (score 1):

From [The Trello App for Slack → /trello commands](http://help.trello.com/article/1049-slack-app):

> Add a card
>
> ```
> /trello add [teammates] [card name]
> ```
>
> Example: `/trello add @john @jessica Finish blog post`